# CoreData implementation swift 3

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm having problems implementing coredata in my project. it seems to be able to save but not to fetch. here's the code

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Utente", in: context)
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    var utente: Profilo? = nil
    let vc = CustomTabBarController() as UIViewController
    let vc1 = LoginController() as UIViewController
    // Configure Fetch Request

    do {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Profilo.fetchRequest()
        let result = try context.fetch(request) as Profilo
        utente = result as Profilo
        print()
        if utente?.type != nil {
            if utente?.type == "students"{
                print("students")
                    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            if utente?.type == "parents"{
                print("parents")
                present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            if utente?.type == "teachers"{
                print("teachers")
                present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        } else {
            print("variable type empty")
            present(vc1, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }
```

i also get the error on the result line:
cannot invoke 'fetch' with an argument list of type (NSFetchRequest)

Comment: Can you post your save to core data please, I'm having trouble with it myself. Thanks !

Comment: I just copied the answer below but now it doesn't work because i changed the model. I'm figuring out how to make it work again

Comment: I managed to make my coredata work so if you want I can post it as an answer here.

Comment: that would be great thank you!!!!

Comment: I posted my code as an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we agreed I'm posting my core data functions, they may not be the best way but they work in my project. My entity is called Goals.

```
// MARK: - Core data funcitons

func loadCoreData(){
    goalsArray.removeAll()

    //let request = NSFetchRequest<Goals>(entityName:"Goals")
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

do{
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Goals> = Goals.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Goals>
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for result in result {
        goalsArray.append(result)
        print("Fetched result goaltitle is \(result.goalTitle!)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()

print("I've fetched the results")
}
catch {
    fatalError("Sthh")
    }
}



func countCoreDataObjects()-> Bool{
           //let request = NSFetchRequest<Goals>(entityName:"Goals")
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do{
        let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Goals> = Goals.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Goals>
        let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if result.count == 0 {
            return false
        } else {return true

        }
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Sthh")
    }

}


func saveToCD(object: goalClassForPassing){

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Goals", in: context)
    let goal = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! Goals



    goal.goalTitle = object.goalName
    goal.id = String(describing:Date())
    goal.imagePath = object.imagePath

    do {
        try context.save()}
    catch {
        fatalError("couldn't save to core data")
    }


    goal.id = String(describing: Date())
    goalObjectToSaveToCD?.id = String(describing: NSDate())
    print(goalObjectToSaveToCD?.goalTitle)
    print("Saved \(goal.goalTitle) - \(goal.id) - \(goal.imagePath) to Core Data")
    loadCoreData()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is supposed to be

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Profilo> = Profilo.fetchRequest()
let result = try context.fetch(request) as! [Profilo] // returns always an array.
```

Consider that the default initializers `CustomTabBarController()` and `LoginController()` won't work.

Comment: The default initializer creates new empty instances of the controllers which are not the same as those designed in the Storyboard.

Comment: yeah but i'm not using the storyboard. Those are the views that i want to show if the conditions are satisfied. What would the sintax be?

Comment: Then you have to load the controllers from nib or create everything programmatically. Anyway the default initializer will not work. But that's beyond the scope of the question.